# How do I connect to a database and fetch array? I have the data in the database but i have no idea how to do this

Tags: arrays, database

```
 <h1>List of Employers</h1>
<?php
     include("connection.php");

?>
     <table border ="1">
<tr>
    <td>Registration Date</td
    <td>Registration ID</td>
    <td>Organization Name</td>
    <td>Contact Name</td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>Amount Due</td>
    <td>Pay Status</td>
    <td>Status</td>
<td>Registration Complete</td>
 </tr>
     $query = "SELECT Registration Date, Registration ID, Organization Name, Contact Name, Total, Amount Due, Pay Status, Status, Registration Complete FROM Business";
     $result = mysql_query($query) 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    print "<tr>"; 
    print "<td>" . $row['Registration Date'] . "</td>"; 
    print "<td>" . $row['Registration ID'] . "</td>"; 
    print "<td>" . $row['Organization Name'] . "</td>"; 
    print "<td>" . $row['Contact Name'] . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $row['Amount Due'] . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $row['Pay Status'] . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>"; 
    print "<td>" . $row['Registration Complete'] . "</td>"; 
    print "</tr>"; 
} 
    print "</table>"; 
?>
```

I cant get the any form of the database to connect to these tables no matter how many different codes I use. This doesnt work and i have no idea what will I've tried so many different things

Comment: Run through a PHP tutorial then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a bit more of your code.

I presume your connection.php contains your code "connection string" to your database?

Comment: With no clue of what your approach to the data-design is you still dont fetch the data. 

A example could be

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE location='UK' AND status='Married'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

Comment: With no clue of what your approach to the data-design is you still dont fetch the data. A example could be(see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138689/echo-specific-rows-from-a-mysql-database) 

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE location='UK' AND status='Married'"; $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    echo "Hi ".$row['first_name'] . " You are from ".$row['location']." and you are ".$row['status']."!";
}